# ACCESS SQL query

Tags: ms-access-2010

**Table1**:

```
GenericID RelatedGenericID
--------- ----------------
25            1566

220           1570

330           1571
```

**Table2**:

```
GenericID GenericName
--------- -----------
25           a

220          b

330          c

1566         d

1570         e

1571         f
```

i want the **result** of the MSaccess query to be:

```
GenericID GenericName RelatedGenericID  RelatedGenericName
--------  ----------- ----------------  ------------------
25           a          1566               d

220          b          1570               e

330          c          1571               f
```

can anyone help me plz. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should give proper formatting to your question...

Comment: What table is RelatedGenericName in?

Comment: There is no RelatedGenericName in the two database tables, the RelatedGenericName is a derived column, see me answer ...

Answer (score 0):

This is built using only the query design window in MS Access. G2, which contains the names, has been added to the design grid twice.

This is how it looks in MS Access 2010 SQL view:

```
SELECT g1.GenericID, g2.GenericName, g2_1.GenericName, g1.RelatedGenericID 
FROM (g1 INNER JOIN g2 ON g1.GenericID = g2.GenericID) INNER JOIN g2 AS g2_1 ON g1.RelatedGenericID = g2_1.GenericID;
```

Tidied:

```
SELECT g1.genericid,
       g2.genericname,
       g1.relatedgenericid,
       g2_1.genericname
FROM   (g1
        INNER JOIN g2
                ON g1.genericid = g2.genericid)
       INNER JOIN g2 AS g2_1
               ON g1.relatedgenericid = g2_1.genericid;
```